# Date of birth JavaScript function stopped working

Tags: javascript

I've been using the following date of birth JavaScript function for years and all of a sudden it has stopped working (again).

The number value should bring back "13". Should say "Xxxx 13 years' xxxx" but currently only displays "Xxxx years' xxxx" so function isn't working basically.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```html
   <p>Xxxx 
    <script>
    var dob='20050613';
    var year=Number(dob.substr(0,4));
    var month=Number(dob.substr(4,2))-1;
    var day=Number(dob.substr(6,2));
    var today=new Date();
    var age=today.getFullYear()-year;
    if(today.getMonth()<month || (today.getMonth()==month && today.getDate()<day))
    document.write(age);
    </script>
    years' xxxx.</p>
```

Comment: You really need to explain exactly how it's not working. Errors? Wrong output? What have you tried to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked for a completely new bit of script and below is an example of a working date of birth function:

```
<p>Xxxx 
<script>
function getAge(DOB) {
var today = new Date();
var birthDate = new Date(DOB);
var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
    age = age - 1;
}
return age;
}
document.write(getAge("06/13/2005"));
</script>
years' xxxx.</p>
```